# How to convert sample request and response xml text into postman request

Tags: postman

Now I have a text file(xml format) as a document for test some web applications but I don't know how to use it in **Postman** request also not able to import it .
[request urls](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z1piW.png)

[sample request and response xml code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gHqDo.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do so via pre-request setup.
You can check the documentation: https://www.postman.com/postman/workspace/postman-answers/documentation/9215231-c7c99fbb-b7f9-48a5-8ddc-192e0f8194e4

[image]